# Finding the cardinality of an orbit of an element

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, group-actions

Let $A = (1 2 3 \dots n)$ be an element of $P_n$. So that the group $P_n$ acts on itself by means of the action of conjugation, for $B \in P_n$,

$$B · A = B A B^{-1}.$$

Stabilizer of $A$ is subgroup; $$\{A^{c} \mid c = 0, \dots , n-1\}.$$

I want to find the cardinality of $Orb_{P_n}(A)$.

So by applying the Orbit stabilizer theorem:

Then for A to act in itself by conjugation then I have that $Orb_{P_n}(A)=ABA^{-1}$ : where $A$ is an element of $P_n$.

[Provided by my friend Andreas]

Proof of the stabilzer of A:

By applying the orbit-stabilizer theorem, you can count how many n-cycles there are.

The result is $n! / n = (n-1)!$, as each $n$-cycle can be written in $n$ different ways,
$$
(12\dots n) = (23\dots n 1) = \dots.
$$

Since the conjugacy class of $(12\dots n)$ consists of all $n$-cycles, orbit-stabilizer tells you that the stabilizer you are looking for (which is called the centralizer of $A$) has order $n$.
Since there are n distinct powers of A, and they clearly stabilize A, and so forth.

Is this correct :O

-nomad609

Comment: I assume that $P_n$ is the permutation group on $n$ symbols. This is normally denoted as $S_n$. Also, your $G$ is $P_n$? There is a mistake here: $Orb_{P_n}(A)=ABA^ {-1}$, must be  $Orb_{P_n}(A)=\{BAB^ {-1}: B \in P_n\}$. How did you find the stabilizer of $A$?

Comment: Yes you are correct sorry. I couldn't manage to input it correctly. I too was ambivalent about the notation used, but yes it should be Sn. Every correction you applied is right. I will add it in one moment.

Comment: There Sir, I have added it in.

Comment: Does any have any thoughts please/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The centralizer of $A=( 1 2 3 \cdots n)$ is $\langle A \rangle$, which is a cyclic group of order $n$. Here, *centralizer* is the same as stabilizer when the action is conjugation. Hence the orbit, in other words, the number of elements in the conjugacy class of $A$ in $S_n$ is $n!/n=(n-1)!$.

Answer (score 3):

It would be this I think:

Suppose that the finite group G acts on the set X, and that x ∈ X.
Then the cardinality of G is the product of the cardinality of the orbit of x and the
cardinality of the isotropy group at x. Writing |S| for the cardinality of a finite set
S, this is
|G| = |G · x| |Gx|.

If anyone can verify this please :)